# Open popuop every 60 seconds with some conditions

Tags: javascript

I need to only show a popup, every 60 seconds once its closed the first time, no matter which page you are on.  if you close it once and search all over the website, you will not see it again for 60 seconds.

How can we do this?

At this moment i got this:

```
//open modal after 60sec
    (function(){

        $( ".my-class" ).trigger( "click" );
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 60000);
    })();
```

But this one will open the popup every time, i assume i will need to use cookies maybe?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to store something in either a cookie or localStorage to keep track between page views.  I'm sure there's a good reason for needing this, but this would drive me insane.

Comment: Try a setInterval() function instead of setTimeout(). setTimeout runs once, while set interval runs an infinite amount of times.

Comment: asked by client...its a private site so i need to show a popup before entering...

Answer (score 0):

After you click the first time you need to trigger a boolean flag with that, 
set a initial var as false and change it to true after the first click, then just do a simple if condition checking if it is true already.

then just do that:

```
setTimeout(arguments.callee, 60000);
```

Comment: Yes, im using this one

if(localStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown'){
       $( ".my-car .search-vehicle" ).trigger( "click" );
  setTimeout(arguments.callee, 60000);
        localStorage.setItem('popState','shown')
    } 

But the problem is that this will not show again the popup...i need to f you close it once and search all over the website, you will not see it again for 60 seconds.
Please note this is a pay per view site thats why the req...

Comment: that happens because your if condition would not be revaluated each 60 second you need to have a event for that, if you watch close the first time works well because you have a event attached (the mouse trigger)

Comment: to solve that, you can have the first listener as you have at the moment that opens the first time and then separated you can have the setTimeout that inside revaluate if it is the first time or not, since you know that the setTimeout will be executed each 60 seconds, the bad here is that even you didn't click yet it will pass on that condition each 60 second is not good for performance

Comment: Can you post the complete code so i can accept your answer?